# How to add PM2 startup script when other computer is pingable

Tags: node.js, database, ubuntu-16.04, pm2

I have 2 Linux server in our environment. One is a web server and one is database server. I want to enable PM2 startup script on both server that If both servers are pingable to each other only than application will auto starts.

How can we do that?

Comment: Hi ,Welcome to stack overflow .Please take the time to read to see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a service that stays on both servers and checks if each are able to ping each other. The same service should execute command to start your node script upon a successful outcome.

Comment: Can you explain it more? what kind of service to write?

Comment: Any program that pings each other and then processes on positive outcome.